# Do the apk that target one android is version supports other android os version?

Tags: android, apk

Consider an app that has been created for android device that supports
ice cream sandwich do this apk support other versions of android??

Answer (score 1):

The apk will run on any android version greater than or equal to `minSdkVersion` i.e >= `minSdkVersion`. The app will run best `in targetSdkVersion` and greater. The android app are supported in newer android version if created as guidelines. [For more info](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html#minsdkversion)

Answer (score 0):

All device with Android version >= to the `minSdkVersion` are supported.

Comment: Note: Supported doesn't mean that the app works flawless on older/lower API's.